# JavaScript array into JSON data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, serialization

I am not very comfortable in JavaScript. This question may be silly, but I could not find any suitable solution.

I have following two arrays.

```
colors = ['red',  'green',  'blue'];
values = [20, 50, 100];
```

Now I want to convert it into a data series, something like,

```
data: [{
    color:  'red',
    value:  20,
}, {
    color:  'green',
    value:  50,
}, {
    color:  'blue',
    value:  100,
}]
```

I looked `JSON.stringify()` and `jQuery.param()` functions, but not clear how to accomplish this.

Comment: JSON is for converting an array or object to text, so you can send it over the network or put it into a file. It has nothing to do with converting one data structure into another data structure.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. It was my mistake. Now I understand that I asked a wrong question. `data`, `color`, `value` etc. are parameters, not a string. So probably I am looking for a function that generates **parameter-value** combination from arrays and can be used in another [function](https://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/2vdvur9L/).

Comment: You have 3 answers that show how to do it. There's no built-in function that does this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you need, you need to create a new array that has elements from both `colors` and `values`, matched on their `index` and then apply `JSON.stringify()` to this new array to convert it into a string.

```
var colors = ['red',  'green',  'blue'];
var values = [20, 50, 100];

var data = [];
$.each(colors,function(i)
{
  data.push({'color' : colors[i], 'values' : values[i]});
});

var a = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(a);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2s67pm8c/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to combine the arrays, you could map the arrays using this snippet:

```
var jsonData =
{
  data: colors.map(function(color, index) {
          return ({ color: color, value: values[index]});
        })
};
var jsonStringified = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

What I've done here is to map the colors array into a new array containing the corresponding value (of the same index) and assigned it to object property data.
The final object I converted to string using JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
    data.push({color:colors[i], value:values[i]});
 }
```